# delete row/entry based on duplicate column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called prospective_shop and one of the column name is 'username'. Username is not set as a primary key, but I wanted to remove all rows that have duplicate username. How can I do this the fastest way?

I tried doing the following:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE  `prospective_shop` ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_name (username);
```

but then it gives me:

```
 Duplicate entry 'calista_shopp' for key 'idx_name'
```

Comment: Do you have specific criteria around which duplicates should be removed?

Comment: Do you want to delete all `'calista_shopp'`s or to leave just one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from prospective_shop
where id not in
(
  select * from 
  (
    select min(id)
    from prospective_shop
    group by username
  ) x
)
```

You can just delete all records that are not the first ones for every unique username. By selecting min(id)` for every username group you make sure not to delete those but all the rest.

In MySQL you can't delete from a table you are selecting from at the same time. You can trick the engine by using another subselect as I did. The `x` is just an alias name for the temp table.

Comment: Heya, this looks great, but can you give some explanation on how this solves the problem (don't forget there's tons of newbies who come to Stack overflow and the solution might not be obvious to them).